# Firebase acces all users data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i want to access all users profile in my firebase database.

The database looks like `'users/useruid/profile'`

how should go about the problem ? 
right know i do :

```
firebaseRef.database().ref(`/users`)
```

if i do `currentUser = firebase.auth()` i only get access to that specific user, i want to access all the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following to access all users:

```
 firebase.database().ref().child("users").on('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var retrievedData = child.val();
var name=child.val().name;
var email=child.val().email;
 //etc
  });
});
```

Assuming you have:

```
users
  userid
     name:...
     email: ...
  userid
     name:...
     email:...
```